# Adding onclick or eventlistener to Createelement with id of div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make a playing field for a game, in which all seperate divs get a different onclick or eventlistener so div 1 would get:

```
reageerOpKlikSpeelveld(1);
```

div 2 would get:

```
reageerOpKlikSpeelveld(2);
```

This is the function creating my divs on the page:

```
function createDivs(amount) {
    for(x=0; x<amount;x++) {
            var vlak = document.createElement('div');
            vlak.className = "vlak";
            document.getElementsByClassName("veld")[0].appendChild(vlak);
            }
        }
```

I basically have no idea how to do this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can save the index of the div to the div itself, and then access it through 'this'.

```js
function createDivs(amount) {
  for (x = 0; x < amount; x++) {
    var vlak = document.createElement('div');
    
    
    vlak.myIndex = x;
    vlak.onclick = function() {
        reageerOpKlikSpeelveld(this.myIndex);
    };
    
    
    vlak.className = "vlak";
    document.getElementsByClassName("veld")[0].appendChild(vlak);
  }
}
```

Comment: Now, to edit stuff in other functions of these divs, e.g

`divs[i].style.backgroundColor = "lightgray"`

What should I do?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Do you simply want to set the background color of all divs to the same color?

Comment: Nevermind, got it working after some fiddling, just had to define var divs like this:

`var divs = document.getElementsByClassName("vlak")`

Answer (score 2):

With jQuery, you could write something like this:

```
function createDivs(amount) {
    for(x=0; x<amount;x++) {
        var vlak = $(document).add("div");
        $(vlak).addClass("vlak");
        $(vlak).attr("id", "MyId-" + x);
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    createDivs(10);

    $(".vlak").on(click, function() {
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        var tab = id.split("-");
        reageerOpKlikSpeelveld(tab[1]);
    });
});
```

Here, you generate 10 divs when document is ready.
Then, the event on click is bound for all divs.

In native Javascript:

```
function createDivs(amount) {
    for(x=0; x<amount;x++) {
        var vlak = document.createElement('div');
        vlak.className = "vlak";
        vlak.id = "MyId-" + x;
        vlak.onclick = function(e) { 
            reageerOpKlikSpeelveld(e.target.id) 
        };
        document.getElementsByClassName("veld")[0].appendChild(vlak);
    }
}

function reageerOpKlikSpeelveld(itemid) {
    var tab = itemid.split("-");
    var id = tab[1];
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I can only use javascript, otherwise this would be a great piece of code. Thanks anyways! I call the createDivs function in my controller's configure function (MVC model)

Comment: All of the above can be accomplished with vanilla JS.

Comment: If I use this, my console says: ControllerMV.js:33 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined